# use of the master branch in Git branching models

Tags: git, branching, gitflow

I've seen branching models with a develop and master branch (with features being merged into develop first), where the master branch was always entirely part of the history of develop and would be fast-forwarded after the build runs and all tests pass.  And I've seen others where the master branch would contain actual merge commits from develop, release or hotfix branches (so fast-forwarding wouldn't even be possible anymore).  I believe the latter is the case in gitflow.

What are the benefits/drawbacks/trade-offs of each approach?  It would seem to me that the first approach ensures that all code that went out to production is also in the develop branch.  But it's unclear how hotfixes are dealt with then.

Answer (score 1):

In [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#gitflow-workflow), an hotfix is a branch that is created from master and in the end is merged back in master AND in develop.

The general (and well known) idea behind the "don't directly commit on master", is to have in master, a state of your code that is completely safe to deploy in production.

However, it can serves other means. [For Github](https://youtu.be/cIJ4sKaoF8A?t=32m4s), the master also serves as a tracking tool to know when a feature is put in production. If you commit on another branch and then fast-forward master on it, you will lose the merge commit, and by extension, you'll just put a lot of tiny commits in your master timeline, losing the ability to revert a whole feature by simply revert the previous merge.

Another problem with this approach, is to know WHEN you can release/deploy. If everyone commit on master, you will have to synchronize all the development to have a coherent state of your code. For monolithic releases with a clear scope, it can be ok, but in my case, as an integration developer, features come and go and you have never a single point in time when "all features are done".

However, not commit in master does not mean having a branch master and a develop. As pointed in the Github presentation, if you do a [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#feature-branch-workflow), you can work only with a master, creating a branch for each feature, and merges them back in master (without fast-forward) at the end.

In my humble opinion, Git Flow (master/develop + features/hotfix/release branches) is more adapted in a context where you don't really know when you'll have to release it (not at each feature done), and when the last release is often the one to hotfix. A gitflow chart can be convoluted, while a feature branching workflow is often more simple to read. The "noise" is often due to release/hotfix commit in what will be deleted branch some minutes after.

**Example for Gitflow**

[image: Example for gitfow]

**Example of graph for Feature Branching Workflow**

[image: Example for feature branch workflow]

Comment: ```If you commit on another branch and then fast-forward master on it, you will lose the merge commit, and by extension, you'll just put a lot of tiny commits in your master timeline, losing the ability to revert a whole feature by simply revert the previous merge``` ==> that's not true: if you fast-forward master on develop, you only have the merge commits from the feature branches into develop.  In the gitflow picture there aren't more commits in develop than in master.

Comment: The interesting part is the opposite : there is additional commit on master than in develop, specially the one for "Tag 1.0". If you create a branch "test", commit two times in it, and then merge --ff master, master will have the additional two commits, nothing more. If you specify the --no-ff, you'll have a third commit, the "Three-Way merge" that is a clean point of when the merge has been done. You dont have that in -ff.

For information, gitflow is a --no-ff unless for feature branch with a single commit in them.

Comment: None of the two cases I described allow for master to be fast-forwarded on a branch "test".  Both assume having a `master` and a `develop` branch, but one uses -ff merge from `develop` to `master` (not from any other branches).  Hence, if other (feature) branches are merged to develop with an explicit commit, fast-forwarding master will mean master will also only have the merge commits in its linear history.

Comment: Note that I tagged this question "gitflow" because I know that at least the official gitflow model has merge commits in master that are not in develop.  But some people seem to use an adapted model where master can be fast-forwarded on develop, for example after all tests pass.

Comment: the name "test" was an arbitrary name for "another branch". Suppose the following scenario : You have two branches, master & develop (develop forked from master, as usual). You code a feature "Feature" in 3 commits in one day (T), "FeaturesCommit1", ""FeaturesCommit2", ""FeaturesCommit3". 2-3 days after (T+3), the manual test are all passed, and you can now merge Feature in master. If you use fast-forward, you'll have the 3 previous commit in your master. If you don't use fast-forward (git merge --no-ff master), you'll have a three-way commit merge that tell you that the feature has been

Comment: merged in (T+3). However, if you had fast-forwarded the merge, you'll just have the three commits with their own respectives date (T) and no information left to now WHEN the feature was merged (T+3). This complicates the possibility to "revert" the T+3 merge since you have to revert all the distinct commits, one after one.

That's why in Git Flow, the --no-ff is forced in all cases EXCEPT the feature branch containing only one commit, merged back into develop.

I really invite you to look at the github talk, the need to use a --no-ff strategy is clear on your master.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but the statement "you can now merge Feature in master" is not in line with any of the two types of workflow the question was about.  Since there is a develop branch, the idea is that features get merged into develop first.  In the first type, develop would be ff-merged into master (which means there **cannot** be any direct merges of features to master, otherwise this would fail), while in the second type there would be another explicit merge commit from develop to master.  I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear on this, I made a small addition to clarify.